# How to fix distcc error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, distcc

I'm trying to get distcc working between two machines CLIENT and SERVER I "think" I have it setup right but I am still getting this error

> (dcc_build_somewhere) Warning: failed to distribute, running locally
>   instead

NOTHING is being compiled on the server.

My configuration is as follows

> CLIENT = 192.168.0.14
>   SERVER = 192.168.0.15

/etc/default/distcc on SERVER

```
 STARTDISTCC="true"
    ALLOWEDNETS="192.168.0.0/24" // Also tried CLIENT IP here
    LISTENER="192.168.0.15" // SERVER IP
    NICE="10"
    JOBS="16"
    ZEROCONF="false"
```

client - yes I know that its set to only compile on the server currently

```
DISTCC_HOSTS="192.168.0.15"
/etc/distcc/host set to 192.168.0.15
$HOME/.distcc/host set to 192.168.0.15
```

command

```
make -jx CC=distcc
```

I have tried on different software repos to see if there was some problem with an individual repo but the problem persists no matter the package.

*EDIT*
The failed to distribute error is a client side error. Server side the log indicates

> distccd[1046] (dcc_job_summary) client: 192.168.0.14:40732 COMPILE_ERROR exit:1 sig:0 core:0 ret:0 time:94ms gcc certs/system_keyring.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading my version of GCC. The client and Server are now running 5.x.

Answer (score 0):

Check the log:

```
DISTCCD_OPTS="${DISTCCD_OPTS} --log-file /var/log/distccd.log"
```

In my case, my log said:

```
(dcc_warn_masquerade_whitelist) CRITICAL! /usr/local/lib/distcc not found. You must see up masquerade (see distcc(1)) to list whitelisted compilers or pass --enable-tcp-insecure. To set up masquerade automatically run update-distcc-symlinks.
```

So I had to run:

```
sudo update-distcc-symlinks
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/distcc /usr/local/lib/distcc # because I compiled from source
```